# iOS Slide/Swipe menu like facebook app

Tags: iphone, ios, menu, facebook-like, slide

I know there are tons of projects, I searched in https://www.cocoacontrols.com/ and found some very interesting, like `MasterDetailController`, that is the simlpest one and I got working very good.

But now I have a problem, and probabbly you can help me with another cool and simple slide control, or just a matter of simple tweak of current control or coding.

The main issue is that the `MasterDetailController` must be set on `self.window.rootViewControler = self.principal;`

```
/* THIS IS THE APPDELEGATE */
// This is the slide menu view controller
UIViewController *master = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"MasterView" bundle: nil];
// This is the body view controller
ViewController *detail = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"ViewController" bundle: nil];
// This is the Master detail controller 'driver'
self.principal = [[[MasterDetailController alloc] initWithMasterViewController: master detailViewController: detail] autorelease];
// Then we set the 'driver' as rootView
self.window.rootViewController = self.principal;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Now, I want more `ViewControllers` to have the `slide menu like facebook app` not just the `rootViewController`.

So, how can I do it?

Thanks.

PS: This is the control I am currently using https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/masterdetailcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/uiscrollslidingpages. Sliding scrolling viewcontroller. Instead of rootviewcontroller, pass this...

Comment: I tried that but I'm not deciding which control (exactly) to use, just needing a slide menu, not sliding scrolling, because there are an existing android app and I should do the same for iOS, so... I cannot change the app navigation =/

Answer (score 3):

if you are creating slide/swipe like facebook

application then follow link which is good example of this

https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController

Comment: This need to be `self.window.rootViewController` too and I cannot add more slide menu to other viewcontroller...

Comment: Think as menu slide view controller is working as tray .. Which comes with appropriate view controller

Answer (score 0):

You assign the slidecontroller to the uiview and then set the rootviewcontroller to your viewcontroller. This means that the slideviewcontroller will only work with the assigned view.

If you want to use the slidecontroller for other viewcontrollers you should do it the other way around and set the rootViewController to the slidecontroller.

Comment: I forgot to comment, that snipped I posted is in `appDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one I wrote. Pretty simple to use. It's built on top of UINavigationcontroller and doesn't require any kind of sub-classing on your view controllers.

https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu

Comment: I've created an issue card on your github.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple library

https://github.com/arturdev/AMSlideMenu

This exactly what you need. 
Its FULLY customizable and with different animations.
In demo project you can see how to implement multiple menus/viewControllers in your app.